# add array to object with two fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a an array chartData which has two values. In "series" I want it to hold an array to which I can push three objects. I do it in order to make a heat map diagram using ngxcharts. However I don't really know how to assign that new array to "series". This is what I have been trying until now:

```
prepareArray(): void
  {
    for(var item of this.transactions)
    {
      let index = this.chartData.findIndex(x => x.name == item.shopperCountryCode);
      if(index === -1)
      {
        this.chartData.push({
           "name": item.shopperCountryCode,
            "series": [] as any[]
        });

          this.chartData.series.push({
             "name": "16-34",
              "value": 0
          });

          this.chartData.series.push({
             "name": "35-50",
              "value": 0
           });

          this.chartData.series.push({
             "name": "51-77",
              "value": 0
          });
      }
      else
      {
        this.age = new Date().getFullYear() - new Date(item.dateOfBirth).getFullYear();
        if(this.age <= 34)
        {
          let subIndex = this.chartData[index].series.findIndex(x => x.name == "16-34");
          this.chartData[index].series[subIndex] = this.chartData[index].series[subIndex].value++;
        }
        if(this.age > 34 && this.age <= 50)
        {
          let subIndex = this.chartData[index].series.findIndex(x => x.name == "35-50");
          this.chartData[index].series[subIndex] = this.chartData[index].series[subIndex].value++;
        }
        if(this.age > 50)
        {
          let subIndex = this.chartData[index].series.findIndex(x => x.name == "51-77");
          this.chartData[index].series[subIndex] = this.chartData[index].series[subIndex].value++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried simple `this.chartData.push({
 "name": item.shopperCountryCode,
 "series": [{
   "name": "16-34",
   "value": 0
  }, {
   "name": "35-50",
   "value": 0
  }, {
   "name": "51-77",
   "value": 0
  }] as any[]
});
`

Comment: Actually no, I'm ashamed I didn't even think about it. It stopped giving an error but now I get " Argument of type 'Number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' " regarding the age. The age is declared outside of function as   age: Number; When I change it to string, it starts telling me it cannot be string cause value is a number. Its quite schizophrenic

Comment: I found problem, i just added unary operator in front of item.dateOfBirth cause seems it indeed was string